# ThreadSanitizer detects a data race, where is the problem?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, data-race

In this sample program, I'm trying to avoid using forward declaration and cyclic dependency exploiting a lambda function (called data_race)

```cpp
struct B{
    int x;
    std::thread* tid;

    B(int _x){
        x = _x;
        tid = NULL;
    }

    ~B(){
        if(tid != NULL) delete tid;
    }

    void run(std::function<void(B*)> f){
        auto body = [&f, this](){
            f(this);
        };

        tid=new std::thread(body);
    }

    void wait(){
        tid->join();
    }
};

struct A{
    int x;
    std::mutex mtx;

    A(int _x){
        x = _x;
    }

    void foo(B* b){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        x = b->x;
    };
};

int main(){
    A a(99);
    std::vector<B> v;

    auto data_race = [&a](B* b){ a.foo(b);};

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        v.push_back(B(i));
    }

    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
        v[i].run(data_race);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
        v[i].wait();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However ThreadSanitizer detects a data race coming from the lambda function data_race. Can you help me understand why? The mutex inside A should be enough to avoid it.  Also, can you help me find a solution?

---

EDIT: Using the forward declaration, the data race is not detected anymore, why? (Posting only the struct, without the main, sorry for the long post)

```cpp
struct B;
struct A{
    int x;
    std::mutex mtx;

    A(int _x){
        x = _x;
    }

    void foo(B* b);
};

struct B{
    int x;
    std::thread* tid;

    B(int _x){
        x = _x;
        tid = NULL;
    }

    ~B(){
        if(tid != NULL) delete tid;
    }

    void run(A& a){
        auto body = [&a, this](){
            a.foo(this);
        };

        tid=new std::thread(body);
    }

    void wait(){
        tid->join();
    }
};

void A::foo(B* b){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    x = b->x;
}
```

Comment: Assignment `x = b->x;` will cause the resulting value of `x` to come from random `B` object, even though access is properly synchronized.

Comment: Also unrelated note: Your class `B` violates the rule of 0/3/5 and will cause undefined behavior, should any `B`, after calling `run` on it, be copied/moved, or destroyed without prior call to `wait`, as could happen when modifying `v` after the `run` calls.

Comment: Side note: it makes no sense of newing a std:: thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a reference to the function-local `f` to the lambda `body`, which is invoked by the `thread` constructor.

This object may not be live anymore when the thread function reaches the call inside `body`.

To expand a bit:

A new thread created by `run` will execute a copy of `body`, which is a lambda containing a reference (`[&f]`) to the object `f`, which has the scope of the function `run` and will be destroyed when the main thread leaves `run`.

The thread function will call `operator()` on its reference to `f` in the line `f(this)` in `body`. This call is already causing undefined behavior if it should happen that `run` in the main thread reaches the scope end before the thread function executed this call. The data race here is, that the main thread may write access memory of `f` to destroy it, non-synchronized with the read access to memory of `f` in the spawned thread.

The intermediate function object can be avoided completely:

```
template<typename F>
void run(const F& f){
    auto body = [this](){
        f(this);
    };

    tid=new std::thread(body);
}
```

This will take the outer lambda `data_race` as a reference, copy this reference into `body` and, as long as you make sure `data_race` in `main` is out-lives all threads, the data race mentioned earlier is avoided.

Your edited code does something similar, i.e. it eliminates the object local to `run`. `a` in `body` will be a reference to the `A` defined in `main` which, again as long as `main` guarantees its lifetime extends beyond that of the threads, will not cause any issues at this point.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause of the data race, but can you help me find a solution?

Comment: your solution worked, but I'm not really sure why...care to explain what's the problem with std::function?

Answer (score 0):

The data race is due to having one `A` object (`a`, declared in main) that is shared by all the different `B` objects, since it is passed by reference to the `data_race` lambda.  This one `A` object is referenced in all those threads created in `B::run`, so the assignment `x = b->x` depends on which thread executes last, hence the data race.